# Moving a file from folder to folder on a server makes it no longer openable until a disconnect and reconnect

Tags: macos, monterey, ventura

My first question here.

We have noticed that if we move a file from one folder to another on a server, that file will no longer open.  The only fix is to disconnect and reconnect from the server.  I've tried this with a number of file types (PDF / jpeg) and it's mostly consistent.

Here are some details/things we've tried:

1. My machine is on Monterey.  My friend's machine is on Ventura.
2. If I mount a volume, either locally (I have a QNAP locally) or via an L2TP VPN (from the menu bar-->connect to a Meraki VPN), or via an always-on Ubiquiti-to-Ubiquiti UDM pro VPN, I can open any file, but if I move that file to another folder (mostly I've tried moving the file UP one level), I can no longer open it.
3. I have tried double clicking and right clicking "open" or "open with".  It doesn't work.
4. If I put the file back in the original folder, it still is non-openable.  Other files will open fine.
5. the only way I can re-open that file is to unmount the share and remount it.  At that point, I can access but the issue repeats.
6. I have tried this with synologies, with a QNAP, and with a Dell server, via SMB and AFP.  No difference.
7. I also tried this from a machine running 10.13 on a client's LAN and it worked fine--no open/close issues.  I feel like this is a big sur or higher issue, but can't be sure about that yet.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: This sounds like a file lock issue.  To confirm if the issue is isolated to machines running Monerey/Ventura, try a completely different machine like a Windows box.  Also, keep in mind that when you create a local mount for a remote resource, all file activities are done locally, not on the remote server.

Comment: Tested this from a Win11 PC on the dedicated VPN and it worked without issue, moving a file back and forth from folders did not cause an issue.

Comment: That's good.  We know it works in Windows so this isn't a server issue.  Ideally, I would love to see it tested in an older version of macOS like Catalina.  Have a look at this [question/answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/378575/119271) and see if any of the suggesttions help